# can you rig bezier curve

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

im using bezier curve and bezier circle to make tubing. im using the tubing to make a body that looks like it was made of cables. can you rig the tubing to make it move like a normal model thats being animated
like an arm being moved

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119527 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154144/make-curve-have-a-fill-and-border/154194

Answer (score 3):

Enter in the edit mode of the curve, select a control point, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> as shortcut select *Hook to New Object*.

Blender will generate an empty as a helper get out from edit mode and select the empty and after that select the rig enter in *Pose Mode,* select the bone that you want to relate the control point of the curve (or the emty object) and use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> , from the menu select *Bone*.
Repeat this for every control point of your character.

It`s hard if you have a lot of curves, try to trick it with other techniques.

Model the character in mesh, use *Multiresolution* and sculpt the tubes after you increase the multiresolution to 4 or 5. After you finish the sculpt reduce the Multiresolution to 0 for prewiev and 4 or 5 for render. Rigg the character.

Add 2 or 3 tubes with the bezier curve technique just for effect.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - Adding a **Shrinkwrap modifier** to the bezier curves.

Option 2 - If you need more precise control of the points on the curve, you can try the **Hook modifier**.

Option3 - Just convert your bezier tubes to mesh using
**Object>Convert to>Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**
Then weight it to your armature like any other mesh.